# Xamarin UWP VSTS NuGet Package Restore Fails

Tags: xamarin, uwp, nuget, azure-pipelines, nuget-package-restore

I have a Xamarin app targeting UWP and Android - I decided to try and ONLY target UWP in VSTS.  I have the following listed in my `packages.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="CommonServiceLocator" version="1.3" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Corcav.Behaviors" version="2.3.6" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.10" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.14" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.29" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.2" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Prism.Core" version="6.3.0" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Prism.Forms" version="6.3.0" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Prism.Unity.Forms" version="6.3.0" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
  <package id="System.Net.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Unity" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Xam.Plugin.Media" version="2.6.2" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Xam.Plugins.Settings" version="2.5.4" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Xam.Plugins.TextToSpeech" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="2.3.3.193" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
</packages>
```

I first received the following error during NuGet package restore:

```
System.IO.Compression 4.1.1 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.IO.Compression on UAP,Version=v10.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win10-x64-aot.
System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.UI.Xaml 4.0.1 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.UI.Xaml on UAP,Version=v10.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win10-x64-aot.
System.Net.Requests 4.0.11 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Net.Requests on UAP,Version=v10.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win10-x64-aot.
Some packages are not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64-aot)
```

However, I worked around this issue by setting the build version to VS 2017 and changing the NuGet version from 3.3 to 3.5 in VSTS, but now I am stuck at the following error:

```
******************************************************************************
Finishing: Get Sources
******************************************************************************
******************************************************************************
Starting: NuGet restore **/*.sln
******************************************************************************
==============================================================================
Task         : NuGet Installer
Description  : Installs or restores missing NuGet packages
Version      : 0.2.29
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613747)
==============================================================================
C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
Active code page: 65001
Detected NuGet version 3.5.0.1938 / 3.5.0
SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
C:\a\_tasks\NuGetInstaller_333b11bd-d341-40d9-afcf-b32d5ce6f23b\0.2.29\node_modules\nuget-task-common\NuGet\3.5.0\NuGet.exe restore -NonInteractive C:\a\1\s\DomoticzHome.sln -NoCache
Failed to load msbuild Toolset
  Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Error: C:\a\_tasks\NuGetInstaller_333b11bd-d341-40d9-afcf-b32d5ce6f23b\0.2.29\node_modules\nuget-task-common\NuGet\3.5.0\NuGet.exe failed with return code: 1
Packages failed to install
```

I see a reference to this same error here https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/3358 but there is no resolution.

How do I fix my NuGet package restore?

Comment: To clarify,  I added a  NuGet Installer build step in VSTS for my UWP project, added the file called 'nuget.config' into my PCL and checked in the file into VSTS.   My file contains the xml above.  When I attempt to build VSTS, I get the error - ##[warning]No package sources were found in the NuGet.config file at C:\a\1\s\nuget.config.

Comment: Is that your `NuGet.config`? It looks more like a `packages.config` file

Comment: Yes it is.  I get the feeling that this is wrong?

Comment: OK from the link you sent me it seems I am wrong and I need to have the Uris for the NuGet packages.

Comment: Since these packages are existing in www.nuget.org, you don't need to specify nugget.config. Is the project created via VS 2017? Try to use Nuget 4.0 instead. (Download nuget4.0 and add to source control, map it to build agent and specify the path in Nuget Install step/task (Select Custom))

Comment: @starain-MSFT why isn't nuget 4.0 or 4.1 an option in VSTS?  Someone else sent me a screenshot in which 4.0 is listed on his VSTS.

Comment: Yes, I think the update is pushing to each VSTS, so someone has but others haven't. (It wasn't existing in my VSTS yesterday, but it's existing now.) So, you need to the update ready. The workaround is that you can add it to source control and map to build agent. On the other hand, what's the result if you use nugget 4.0?

Comment: I am using VS2017 and attempting to build a Xamarin UWP project at the moment.   Looking at NuGet there is a NuGet.Core at v2.14.0 and v4 NuGet.Client and NuGet.VisualStudio - which am I suppose to use?

Comment: Just checked and NuGet 4 is an option - I am rebuilding now ... more to follow.

Comment: OK the build is failing.  Says there are missing NuGet packages.  I have logs ...

Comment: 4 error(s), 1 warning(s)
Build - 4 error(s), 1 warning(s)
DomoticzHome\DomoticzHome\DomoticzHome.csproj(233):DomoticzHome\DomoticzHome\DomoticzHome.csproj(233,5): Error : This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.
C:\Users\buildguest\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.6.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Native.Compiler.targets(37):C:\Users\buildguest\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.6.0\build\Microsoft.Net.

Comment: Native.Compiler.targets(37,5): Error : The Microsoft.Net.Native.Compiler package, included in Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform 5.3 and later, is only supported in Visual Studio 2017 and later. You can downgrade the version of the Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatorm NuGet package to 5.2.* or earlier for Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: I selected VS2017 and not sure if downgrading UWP is possible??

Comment: Do you still use Hosted VS2017 build agent? Can you share whole build log here?

Comment: Yes using vs2017. Logs are here<a href="https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mv3gx9q7zcwpyqs/AACwknGYLrNtWFu3EJAO9aS8a?dl=0">file</a>

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue with a new project? If so, you can share it on the OneDrive. The build log just contains Nuget package missing error, not UniversalWindowsPlatform 5.3 error.

Comment: I made a test with simple UWP app, UniversalWindowsPlatform 5.3 and Hosted VS2017 agent, it works fine. So the issue may related to your project.

Comment: I am also using Xamarin Prism Forms project.

Comment: Can you share a simple project on the OneDrive?

Comment: Well I had to rebuild the project twice but it is building.  Considering this issue closed.